# how to create a cookie array and reverse it

Tags: javascript, arrays, cookies

I would like to get a cookies value by its key rather than name but the first key gives me the last cookie and the second = gets the second from last etc etc. so I reversed the array. so why is it not working?

```
function getByKey(key){ 
 var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    var rev = cookies.reverse();
    return rev[key];
}
getByKey(2);
```

http://codepen.io/tarranjones/pen/FIzlt

any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to debug with console:

```
console.log(document.cookie.split(";")[1]);
console.log(getByKey(1));
```

Also, my codepen with your function (with small difference) works.

replace this block of code;

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
var rev = cookies.reverse();
return rev[key];
```

with this block

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
return cookies.reverse()[key];
```

http://codepen.io/zefirka/pen/ndtHG

Comment: Thank you your edited function was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: The function is exactly the same, the difference is in how it's applied.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getByKey()` function would probably work fine, but you're not using it in the codepen.

```
a = document.cookie.split(';')
s = a.reverse();
```

`reverse()` will alter the original array, so you end up reversing `a` and pointing `s` to the same (reversed) array.

Possibly the easiest way to make a reversed *copy* of an array is:

```
for( var i = a.length - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; --i, ++j ) {
    s[ j ] = a[ i ];
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vwErt